# 915Mhz vs Wifi (speed impact of duty cycle limitations)

Tags: esp32

I am currently using an esp32 with Wifi. I need at least 15kByte/s constant throughout. This works fine but I am not happy with the range.

I came across the RFM69HCW 915MHz module. It is stated with 300 kbps.

Now what is confusing me are duty cycle regulations. Various countries have a 1% limit.
Is this limit considered in the 300 kbps? Or do I effectively only get 3 kbps because I cannot constantly send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

300kbps is the data transmission rate. Not the throughput rate.

That means that yes, if you only transmit for 1% of the time then for 1% of the time you are getting 300kbps - i.e., 3kbps as you correctly surmised.